# Reading byte array from spring boot into angular and displaying content on a new page

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to read in a byte array from a springboot application. The springboot app returns a list of items with a json field called: *file_item* which contains the byte array value of the corresponding blob. My goal is to have to have the file appear in a new window after clicking the correlating download button.

Currently I'm receiving an error that the site cannot be reached.

JSON Response from backend:

```
[{
    "uid": 1,
    "description_text": "json file for cars",
    "version_number": "1.0",
    "mime_type": "json",
    "file_item": "W3sNCiJtYWtlIjogIkZvcmQiLCANCiJtb2RlbCI6ICJQaW50byIsDQoieWVhciI6IDE5OTcNCn0sDQp7DQoibWFrZSI6ICJOaXNzYW4iLCANCiJtb2RlbCI6ICJBbHRpbWEiLCANCiJ5ZWFyIjogMjAwNQ0KfQ0KXQ=="
}]
```

data-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

export interface Records {
    uid: number; 
    description_text: String;
    version_number: String; 
    mime_type: String; 
    file_item: Blob; 
}

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    private baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    getitems() {
        return this.httpClient.get(this.baseURL + '/getRecord');
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-ui';
  items: Records[];
  ImageSource: any;

  constructor(private _ds: DataService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._ds.getitems().subscribe((data: Records[]) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.items = data;
    });
  }

  /* CRUD Methods [PrimeNG API] */
  onRowDownload(item: Records) {
    console.log(item.file_item);
    let objectURL = 'data:application/json;base64,' + item.file_item;
    this.ImageSource = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
    window.open(this.ImageSource);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<p-table [value]="items" dataKey="uid">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th>UID</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Version</th>
      <th>Mime Type</th>
      <th style="width:8em"></th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-ri="rowIndex">
    <tr>
      <td>{{rowData.uid}}</td>
      <td>{{rowData.description_text}}</td>
      <td>{{rowData.version_number}}</td>
      <td>{{rowData.mime_type}}</td>
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <button pButton type="button" icon="pi pi-download" class="ui-button-info"
          (click)="onRowDownload(rowData)"></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Comment: Please provide more error logs.

Comment: Here is the only log I receive from the URL being returned: http://localhost:4200/SafeValue%20must%20use%20[property]=binding:%20data:application/json;base64,W3sNCiJtYWtlIjogIkZvcmQiLCANCiJtb2RlbCI6ICJQaW50byIsDQoieWVhciI6IDE5OTcNCn0sDQp7DQoibWFrZSI6ICJOaXNzYW4iLCANCiJtb2RlbCI6ICJBbHRpbWEiLCANCiJ5ZWFyIjogMjAwNQ0KfQ0KXQ==%20(see%20http://g.co/ng/security#xss) @MaxPeng